# MS SQL to MySQL Conversion

Tags: sql-server, mysql

Is there a tool available that converts queries written as triggers, stored procedures and functions written in MS SQL 2008 to MySql? We switched databases and now I need to rewrite a bunch of queries for MySql and would like to automate the process as much as possible.

Comment: First, have you converted the tables?